# How can I split a message and resend the second part into a text channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to split a message when someone uses this tip command and get the second part of the message.

In other words, after someone types `&tip <@607942707620610087> 10 satoshi` I want to be able to get the `10 satoshi` part and put it into the general.send command.

```
var general = client.channels.find(channel => channel.id === "605819397524946972");

if(message.content.startsWith("&tip <@607942707620610087>")) {
    message.author.send("Thanks for the donation!");
    general.send("<@" + message.author.id + "> just donated ")
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var general = client.channels.find(channel => channel.id === "605819397524946972");

if(message.content.startsWith("&tip <@607942707620610087>")) {
    let args = message.content.slice("&").split(' ');
    message.author.send("Thanks for the donation!");
    general.send(`${message.author} just donated ${args[2]`)
};
```

`message.content.slice("&").split(' ')`This will slice the prefix and split the message like that `("&tip <@607942707620610087> 10 satoshi"` Where `tip will be our (args[0]), <@607942707620610087> (args[1]) and finally 10 satoshi will be ours (args[2]))`